# How Install and Configure Hue without CDH to manage HDFS

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

I want to install and configure Hue to manage my HDFS file using the web?

I have installed single node Hadoop cluster on my local machine.

I have found this [Hue Install Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/hue_ins_0.html#hue_install_guide), which installs Hue through Cloudera manager and CDH, but I want to install it without using Cloudera manager and CDH.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [installation documentation on Hue's Github](https://github.com/cloudera/hue#getting-started), or official [documentation page](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/admin-manual/manual.html#installation) and you'll have

1. The latest build of Hue (rather than rely on old versions that CDH has)
2. The ability to run it against any Hadoop cluster (provided the correct [setup of `hue.ini` config file](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/admin-manual/manual.html#configuration_1))